# Add enum type column to table

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, alter-table

im trying to add a new column to my existing table 'Results', and it seems to be very easy but I cant see the mistake.

Here is my code:

```
SQL> Alter table results add column CAL ENUM('A','B');


ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

What am I missing?

I've read this from [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) and this from [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Data-Type/UseALTERTABLEtoconvertthenamecolumntoanENUMthatliststhecolorsinthedesiredsortorder.htm) but cant see the difference to mine.

Thanks, and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: `ENUM’ is a [MySQL datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/enum.html), not an [Oracle RDBMS data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm). They are not the same product and have different dialects of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, with an ORA- error I am assuming that this is an oracle database, and not mysql. you have both tags and you are linking to MySQL example, but the error is not a MySQL error.

Assuming that this IS an Oracle DB, then there is no native ENUM data type. You have to do this as follows: First - you add the column with a correctly defined data type, and second you create a constrained list of permitted values on that column as a check constraint.

```
Alter table results add (cal varchar2(1));
Alter table results add constraint chk_cal CHECK (cal in ('A','B')) ENABLE;
```

(EDITED to fix brackets in constraint creation line)

Comment: sorry - missed a set of brackets. I'm away from my DB... One sec and I'll edit.